# Правильный запуск *.exe - C#

Tags: c#

Добрый день ребят, нуждаюсь в Вашей помощи, уже бьюсь неделю над одним вопросом, ничего в голову не приходит
Есть игровой лаунчер, естественно он лежит не в папке с игрой, но используя file.Dialog узнаю папку где лежит game.exe
При запуске этого самого exe игра запускается, но ничего не происходит далее, висит на этапе загрузки ресурсов.

Помогите, мозг кипит!

Код пробовал разный

//И так не запускается

```
string gamePatch = @"D:\Games\MyGames\"

public void ExecuteAsAdmin(string fileName)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info =
            new ProcessStartInfo("gamePatch", "");
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.UseShellExecute = true;
            info.Verb = "runas";
            proc.StartInfo = info;
            proc.Start();
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ExecuteAsAdmin("Start.exe");
}

//И просто так тоже не хочет
Process.Start(gamePatch + "Start.exe");\
```

Comment: Ну у многих игр методы загрузки разные. Некоторые требуют определенные параметры запуска (например ключ авторизации или другие какие то опции), некоторые отслеживают от куда была и кем запущена игра, а некоторые так и вовсе блокируют запуск сторонними методами, у кого то и вовсе может быть проблема в определении пути к файлам и за них это делает лаунчеры. Вам нужно это изюминку и узнать. Как мы то можем Вам помочь, когда даже игру не знаем?

Comment: Какая у вас цель? Запустить из под админа? Добавить параметры запуска?